# How can I mark a message as read in MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

I use MailKit to read some messages from a GMail Account. Works great, but when my application has read a message, I want to mark the message as read, and save that state to GMail. Is this possible with MailKit? I have not found anything about it yet.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The way to mark messages as read using the IMAP protocol is to set the `\Seen` flag on the message(s).

To do this using MailKit, you will first need to know either the index(es) or the UID(s) of the messages
that you would like to set the `\Seen` flag on. Once you have that information, you will want to call
one of the `AddFlags()` methods on the `ImapFolder`. For example:

```
folder.AddFlags (uids, MessageFlags.Seen, true);
```

To mark messages as unread, you would *remove* the `\Seen` flag, like so:

```
folder.RemoveFlags (uids, MessageFlags.Seen, true);
```

Comment: The RemoveFlags function doesn't seem to have any effect. Could you please modify your answer to include the connection to the server too?

Comment: Make sure that you open the folder in `FolderAccess.ReadWrite` mode.

Comment: Thanks. Works now perfectly.

Comment: Is there way to do it having `MimeMessage` only without knowing in what folder it is?

Comment: No, there's no way to set the flags without knowing the folder.